# Can't mix metrics (aggregated values) and dimensions (non-aggregated values) in Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio, google-analytics-4

[image]
I'm trying to create a new field - Impression in Looker Studio like below. The formula worked in Tableau but could not work in Looker Studio.
"Sorry, calculated fields can't mix unaggregated data (dimensions) and aggregated data (metrics). Please check the aggregation types of the fields used in this formula"

How to solve this issue?